# При деплое web-приложения не видит файл конфигурации БД

Tags: java, база-данных, rest, servlet

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему. Есть REST сервис с использованием JDBC и Servlet. Параметры подключения к БД  вынесены в файл.

Проблема такая: при деплое war в tomcat не удается установить подключение, так как не находит файл конфигурации БД, соответственно сервлет отвечает на запросы ошибкой. При этом без деплоя, в идее, все работает отлично, файл видит, подключение поднимается.

Подключение через hikariCP, но пробовал и через драйвер, так же не видит файл при деплое, так что разницы нет.

Класс подключения

```
package ru.kravchenko.connection;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DataSource {

    private static final String APP_CONF = "src/main/resources/datasource.properties";
    private static HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig(APP_CONF);
    private static HikariDataSource dataSource;

    static {
        dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    private DataSource() {
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В идее всё работает, потому что там действительно есть директория /src/main/... Но при упаковке в war-файл она теряется. Я точно не помню, какой там путь, но вы можете открыть варник и посмотреть, куда положится проперти-файл. И от этого уже соответственно прописывать путь в коде.